# Buttons, maps not working and not setting markers for the maps

Tags: java, android, android-studio

can somone help me? I create a nearby places in your current location. here are the codes

Main code of the activity
public class Placefinder extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
private ActivityPlacefinderBinding binding;
private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
private static final int Request_code = 101;
private double lat, lng;
ImageButton hospital, police, fire_station;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    binding = ActivityPlacefinderBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    hospital = findViewById(R.id.hospital);
    police = findViewById(R.id.police);
    fire_station = findViewById(R.id.fire_station);

    fusedLocationProviderClient =
            LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    hospital.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder
                    ("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
            stringBuilder.append("location=" + lat + "," + lng);
            stringBuilder.append("&radius=1000");
            stringBuilder.append("&type=hospital");
            stringBuilder.append("&sensor=true");
            stringBuilder.append("&key=" + getResources().getString(R.string.google_maps_key));

            String url = stringBuilder.toString();
            Object dataFetch[] = new Object[2];
            dataFetch[0] = mMap;
            dataFetch[1] = url;

            FetchData fetchData = new FetchData();
            fetchData.execute(dataFetch);
        }
    });

    police.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder
                    ("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
            stringBuilder.append("location=" + lat + "," + lng);
            stringBuilder.append("&radius=1000");
            stringBuilder.append("&type=police");
            stringBuilder.append("&sensor=true");
            stringBuilder.append("&key=" + getResources().getString(R.string.google_maps_key));

            String url = stringBuilder.toString();
            Object dataFetch[] = new Object[2];
            dataFetch[0] = mMap;
            dataFetch[1] = url;

            FetchData fetchData = new FetchData();
            fetchData.execute(dataFetch);
        }
    });

    fire_station.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder
                    ("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
            stringBuilder.append("location=" + lat + "," + lng);
            stringBuilder.append("&radius=1000");
            stringBuilder.append("&type=fire_station");
            stringBuilder.append("&sensor=true");
            stringBuilder.append("&key=" + getResources().getString(R.string.google_maps_key));

            String url = stringBuilder.toString();
            Object dataFetch[] = new Object[2];
            dataFetch[0] = mMap;
            dataFetch[1] = url;

            FetchData fetchData = new FetchData();
            fetchData.execute(dataFetch);
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    getCurrentLocation();
}

private void getCurrentLocation() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, Request_code);
        return;
    }

    LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setInterval(6000);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
    LocationCallback locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(@NonNull LocationResult locationResult) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location result is=" + locationResult, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if (locationResult == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Current location is null" + locationResult, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

            for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Current location is " + location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    };

    fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, null);

    Task<Location> task = fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
    task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
            if (location != null) {
                lat = location.getLatitude();
                lng = location.getLongitude();

                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Current Location"));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15));
            }
        }
    });
}

@SuppressLint("MissingSuperCall")
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case Request_code:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                getCurrentLocation();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

}

The maps is not showing and causing error, location not setting. dont know what to fix on it. hope you can help

The maps is not showing and causing error, location not setting. dont know what to fix on it. hope you can help. I tried calling the getUrl to get the location coordinates of the place and appasync to update the pins on the neaby places. buttons dont work too.